# Trying to get rid of unwraps

Tags: rust

I have this line in my program:

`let date = file.metadata().unwrap().modified().unwrap();`

Can it be changed into form of `if let Ok(date) = file.metadata().something....` and still be one liner?

Forgot to add: can't use ? operator, bc this is in a closure in `for_each()`.

Comment: learn about ? operator

Comment: cannot use ? bc this code is in a closure

Comment: You can use `?` in closures. You just have to consistently return a `Result` from the closure.

Comment: But this closure is in `for_each()` Compiler is saying it wants nothing `()` as a return value.

Comment: You can use `try_for_each()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then):

```rust
if let Ok(date) = file.metadata().and_then(|md| md.modified()) {
    // stuff
}
```

Using the ["try" operator (`?`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator):

```rust
// containing function returns `Result<T, E>` where `E: From<io::Error>`
let date = file.metadata()?.modified()?;
```

Comment: Cannot use ?, but first idea with `and_then` looks pretty good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside a closure which must return `()`, and you want to ignore the error, I'd actually recommend using `let else` as such:

```rust
let Ok(metadata) = file.metadata() else { return };
let Ok(date) = metadata.modified() else { return };
// ...
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't increase the indentation level.